# PHP equivalent to C# string formatting

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to duplicate my C# string formatting where i can do something like this:

```
Console.Writeline("My name is [0].  I have been a [1] for [2] days.", "bob", "member", "12")
```

I want to be able to do this in PHP, but as far as I know the only function that resembles this is sprintf().  Is there a function that is identical to the one above

```
echo function("My name is [0].  I have been a [1] for [2] days.", "bob", "member", "12")
```

Comment: What's wrong with `sprintf()`? It is more or less identical to C#'s string formatting.

Comment: The c# version is type-agnostic; you don't have to specify anything about datatypes or numbers vs. strings if you don't want to.  In the simplest form all you need to identify is where in the format string to put specific data items.

Comment: More than identical, you write less, as you have to use two characters instead of 3, and then is the obvious benefit to format floats and other things.

Comment: When you need echo, you can just use printf.

Comment: @Joe If you simply specify everything as `%s`, `sprintf` is basically type-agnositc as well. You don't *have* to use any of the other types.

Comment: @alec No, there's no built-in function with identical syntax. You can of course write your own. Mind telling us why `sprintf`/`printf` are inadequate or what other similarities to `Writeline` you're looking for?

Comment: With C#'s String.Format() you can "arrange" the parameters in any order you like in the format string, e.g. `String.Format("[3] [1] [2]", x, y, z);`. If there's legacy code that has to be translated to php it _might be_ nice to have that feature as well.

Comment: @Volker `sprintf` allows that as well, only the syntax is not as nice: `%1$s`.

Comment: @deceze 5 examples for argument swapping on the manual page and I never noticed that. thanks.

Comment: I don't mind sprintf(), I am just surprised that there isnt an identical function.  I guess you can simple convert all values to strings and use %s, but i am surprised there is no {} method of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own function like e.g.

```
<?php
function Format($format /*, ... */) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[(\\d)\]/',
        function($m) use($args) {
            // might want to add more error handling here...
            return $args[$m[1]+1];
        },
        $format
    );
}

$x = 'a';
$y = 'b';
echo Format('1=[1], 0=[0]', $x, $y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could inline variables in the string:

```
$frob = "John";
$foo = "Hello $frob!";
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I would have surprised me, if it did.